# ANOVA with unbalanced sample sizes across levels of the repeated measures factor

Tags: anova, count-data

I have a design with a group x condition design, whereby some of the repeated measures (conditions) have missing data. Thus, I have, for instance, 10 values at condition A, but only 8 values at condition B, etc.

In more detail, my dependent variable is a count of how frequently an event (clicks by participants) happens per unit of time, across the contiguous regions of time in which the duration of a song has been partitioned. There are 3 types of such regions, unevenly defined throughout the song's length - this is my 'within' factor; and there are two songs, with clicks from different participants used in each song, this being my 'between' condition. The data looks something like this:
[image]

I want to compare my DV across the song x region type design. However, my stats package (the Measures of Effect Size [Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32398-hhentschke-measures-of-effect-size-toolbox) for Matlab) requires that each within-subjects (repeated measures) factor have the same number of samples at every level. Thus I am unable to do an ANOVA because of the unbalanced sample sizes across conditions. I think other packages have this restriction also.

I could superficially get around the problem by defining the 'event type' to be a between-subjects factor, which removes the requirement for balanced equal sample sizes across event types. However, reading a [discussion](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_how_to_account_for_uneven_sample_sizes_using_a_two-way_repeated_measures_ANOVA_in_SPSS) on this topic made me think whether an ANOVA is in fact suitable at all in my case, since the different values obtained for each region type do not really represent a 'repeated' measure. If not, what is the appropriate statistical model to use?

Comment: This is not entirely clear. Could you present (a part of) the data table, or (a link to) the full data set? With data represented as counts of clicks, with another variable giving the length of the corresponding time interval, you might try a (mixed models) Poisson regression.

Comment: Thanks! I've uploaded the data [here](https://we.tl/t-0sJsczFnKw).